# Set Bootstrap modal content to scroll if height exceeds browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have seen so many people asking about this, but no real solid reliable answer.

If the height of the modal exceeds the browser's inner height, I want the red-bordered Div to have a scroll bar to keep the modal within the browser view.

```css
#scrollbox {
  border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="Launch Modal">

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        Hello, below is some text in a div that should start scrolling if the height of the modal exceeds the browser.
        
        <p><div id="scrollbox">
          the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
          the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
          the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
          the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
          the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
          the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
          the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
          the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
          the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
          the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### For Bootstrap versions >= 4.3

Bootstrap 4.3 added new scroll feature to modals. This makes only the **modal-body** content scroll if the size of the content would make the page scroll. This might not work for the OP's situation since they have other content in the **modal-body**, but it might be helpful to someone else. To use it, just add the class **modal-dialog-scrollable** to the same div that has the **modal-dialog** class.

Here is an example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalScrollable">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalScrollable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalScrollableTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalScrollableTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
        the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
        the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
        the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
        the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
        the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
        the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
        the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
        the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
        the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### For Bootstrap versions < 4.3 (old answer)

You can do this using `overflow-y:auto` and [vh units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths). Set the `max-height` property of your `scrollbox` to `100vh` (full viewport height) and subtract some arbitrary number of pixels to account for everything outside the `scrollbox` (that you want to keep inside the viewport). Then add the `overflow-y:auto` rule so that if the content exceeds the `max-height`, a scrollbar will appear. This is pretty similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39090218/2518200) except using CSS instead of jQuery.

```css
#scrollbox {
border: 1px solid red;
overflow-y: auto;
max-height: calc(100vh - 150px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="Launch Modal">

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        Hello, below is some text in a div that should start scrolling if the height of the modal exceeds the browser.
        
        <p><div id="scrollbox">
          the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
          the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
          the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
          the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
          the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
          the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
          the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
          the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
          the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
          the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, I never saw this `100vh` before. I've always used `calc(100% -`.

Comment: @DanielWilliams 100% would evaluate to 100% of its parent, while 100vh would evaluate to 100% of the viewport.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **jquery** to asign a **max-height** in base to the height of the window, i use this code for that situations:

Jquery:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    // Get the height of the window
    var height = $(window).height();
    $('#scrollbox').css('max-height', height+'px');
});
</script>
```

if you want, you can subtract pixels to the height of the window, for example i want to subtract 100px to the height of the window:

```
var height = ($(window).height() - 100);
```

Css:

```
#scrollbox{
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

i hope will be helpful.

Regards!

Comment: Works nice, but I would change `$(window).height();` to `$(document).height();` to get the height of the actual browser, not just the HTML content within.

Answer (score 0):

I added this css to my project and now I have the bootstrap modals to scroll when they are too long.

```
.modal {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it