# How to show large text on alert box of browser and prevent text trimming?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, alert

Have a huge amount of data that should show in the alert box, but it is showing only part of the text not the full data.

In the alert box only this is visible:

> ["19467,1496257152583","19227,1496256651094","19469,1496257033968","17285,1496256471404","19220,1496256594258","18372,1496256536964","16194,1496256424723","16193,1496256776846","11989,1496256462293","11982,1496256483197","11984,1496256687240","11741,1496256589195","19228,1496256434554","17298,1496256685353","17052,1496256466753","11514,1496257183963","11998,1496256573293","10428,1496256894906","12607,1496256571750","13939,1496256673224","10662,1496257161657","10664,1496256703046","10421,1496256766491","11510,1496256816932","10423,1496256892120","17266,1496257056527","19445,1496257108976","16179,1496256583599","17264,1496256433397","18111,1496257210348","19684,1496257495679","12814,1496256522654","10634,1496257173881","10879,1496256469178","12813,1496256904570","11725,1496256508218","11969,1496256734239","10870,1496256773736","10632,1496256982102","19456,1496257649377","18367,1496256443474","15096,1496256780149","18126,1496257620858","19457,1496256792691","17275,1496257620858","13914,1496256881306","12826,1496256416181","10403,1496256456173","11979,1496256648063","11739,1496256553205","10408,1496257201759","10882,1496257757516","11970,1496256914393","12821,1496256667576","12822,1496256486550","17487,1496256756935","10609,1496256782066","11944,1496256595655","10859,1496256543305","18337,1496256990568","10853,1496256474978","16164,1496256439240","17257,1496257553677","17016,1496256666133","17258,1496256558603","17493,1496256417377","16166,1496256899368","11955,1496256416476","10624,1496257088509","10868,1496256674811","11714,1496256881306","11956,1496257166497","11959,1496256421712","11717,1496256442405","10861,1496256713788","11711,1496256497302","16374,1496256778384","19642,1496256443977","18314,1496257426353","16136,1496256579644","14198,1496257148353","11921,1496256700378","10832,1496256966661","11923,1496256922278","16379,1496256505633","17469,1496256453470","19888,1496257144686","10831,1496257100209","18317,1496256430275","19648,1496256434988","18322,149625641931

But need more than this text in alert box, how to do this?

Is there a way to increase alert box size? Or else can we use jQuery to see all of the data?

Here is the complete data that need to be displayed:

> ["19467,1496257152583","19227,1496256651094","19469,1496257033968","17285,1496256471404","19220,1496256594258","18372,1496256536964","16194,1496256424723","16193,1496256776846","11989,1496256462293","11982,1496256483197","11984,1496256687240","11741,1496256589195","19228,1496256434554","17298,1496256685353","17052,1496256466753","11514,1496257183963","11998,1496256573293","10428,1496256894906","12607,1496256571750","13939,1496256673224","10662,1496257161657","10664,1496256703046","10421,1496256766491","11510,1496256816932","10423,1496256892120","17266,1496257056527","19445,1496257108976","16179,1496256583599","17264,1496256433397","18111,1496257210348","19684,1496257495679","12814,1496256522654","10634,1496257173881","10879,1496256469178","12813,1496256904570","11725,1496256508218","11969,1496256734239","10870,1496256773736","10632,1496256982102","19456,1496257649377","18367,1496256443474","15096,1496256780149","18126,1496257620858","19457,1496256792691","17275,1496257620858","13914,1496256881306","12826,1496256416181","10403,1496256456173","11979,1496256648063","11739,1496256553205","10408,1496257201759","10882,1496257757516","11970,1496256914393","12821,1496256667576","12822,1496256486550","17487,1496256756935","10609,1496256782066","11944,1496256595655","10859,1496256543305","18337,1496256990568","10853,1496256474978","16164,1496256439240","17257,1496257553677","17016,1496256666133","17258,1496256558603","17493,1496256417377","16166,1496256899368","11955,1496256416476","10624,1496257088509","10868,1496256674811","11714,1496256881306","11956,1496257166497","11959,1496256421712","11717,1496256442405","10861,1496256713788","11711,1496256497302","16374,1496256778384","19642,1496256443977","18314,1496257426353","16136,1496256579644","14198,1496257148353","11921,1496256700378","10832,1496256966661","11923,1496256922278","16379,1496256505633","17469,1496256453470","19888,1496257144686","10831,1496257100209","18317,1496256430275","19648,1496256434988","18322,149625641931
>
> **2","15295,1496257013599","17478,1496256664567","17471,1496256786635","15057,1496257195469","19891,1496256929111","15297,1496256506899","19890,1496257085211","15292,1496256524687","15290,1496256674811","10846,1496256549277","11934,1496256450581","16149,1496256457378",**

Comment: Why don't you create your own alert component to display it?

Comment: Why not print it to the console?

Comment: maybe an alert is the wrong tool for the job. And no, there is no settings for alert() so there is nothing you can do other than rethink your approach.

Comment: Try this http://bootboxjs.com/ it is very simple to use

Comment: See [How many characters allowed in an alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864533/how-many-characters-allowed-in-an-alert-box-javascript#6864674)

Comment: Alert is *definitely* not the right tool for this job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a jquery popup plugin allowing scrolling, like this one :

- https://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/jQuery-Plugin-For-Scrollable-Modal-Dialog-Long-Dialog.html,
- demo : https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Scrollable-Modal-Dialog-Long-Dialog/

You can also see this stackoverflow discussion : [Set Bootstrap modal content to scroll if height exceeds browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090147/set-bootstrap-modal-content-to-scroll-if-height-exceeds-browser)

The idea behind this is that you put a scrolling div in the bootstrap/jquery popup that has a fixed height...

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a big alert box too for my android phone. I just need some alert boxes for test. So while I coded it in javascript anyway, maybe you can use it. (it's a bit simple I agree)

```
// Your long text
var longtext = "fdkvjakb dfkbkabf bvb, kakjbbr qwerty aserty kebab....etc";

alertalert();
function alertalert() {
    var wordArray = longtext.split(" "); // Split at spaces into array.
    var word;
    var story;
    for (i=0; i <= wordArray.length; i++) {
        word = wordArray[i];
        story = story + word + " "; // Fill the story
        if (story.length > 300) { // Adjust nbr of words per alert here.
            alert(story);
            story = ""; // Empty story for next alert.
        }
    }
} // End function alertalert
```